# PySpark - perform operation per column of dataframe in parallel

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with 50 feature columns and one output column, and want to fit an individual model from each feature to the output, in parallel. Is there a simple way to do this in PySpark?

Performing the fitting of each model sequentially seems to be inefficient, as each model is independent of each other.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

While Spark-dataFrames can bear many-models in column-abstractions, the core miss is in forgetting that the Spark uses them "inside" a stream-process flow with a "deferred", ALAP happening execution (a trick for "eviction" of use-less parts of the dataFrame computations (if these are "later" not used further on, so why to compute them ever?) and for latency masking by a split-work).

What does it mean?

We may imagine what could we do, if we load SAND into first 1000 wagons, CEMENT into next 1000 wagons and WATER into next 1000 wagons, such "Spark"-o-train will never be any faster, if the goal is to mix BETON (from SAND, CEMENT and WATER) and load it into the last 1000 wagons, attached somewhere a few miles behind the last wagon with WATER.

If one would disconnect such a composed "Spark"-o-train and moved all the BETON-process-relevant wagons well "aligned" side by side ( so one also has to build at least -4- PARALLEL rail-tracks and add thus many ENGINES for doing so "in-motion" ), that and only that would permit to mix(compute)-and-store the resulting BETON in a true-`[PARALLEL]` fashion, given no sequential-(re)-ordering and no concurrent-(re)-use, the less blocking, of sufficiently many resource, enough to fetch, process and store all the block of the 1000 wagons-at-once in such a superfast specialised, dedicated BETON-mixing ASAP Quad-o-train, no matter how many wagons are still hanging behind the last wagons with our "DATA"-for-BETON (be it attached on the WATER-, SAND- or CEMENT- feeding wagons on their respective rail-tracks -- this still runs BETON ASAP, with a single latency step - a time to fetch-{ SAND | CEMENT | WATER }-at-once into BETON-mixing-wagon and here we are, no faster process exists).

Not having that many resources' capacities in such a non-blocking, zero-sharing, zero-latency resources-rich ecosystem?

Then expect anything but way less performant, than that.

Sharing resources, serial data-fetches (in dataFrames' streams) and just deferring a process to some later moment in time ALAP is fair to be called just a latency masking, sometimes helpful, if data-content and computing-graphs permit, not in general.

Sorry, but this is how the real world execution actually happens, once we go and look onto internal working, ignoring the marketing evangelised mythology.

Loading many-features onto the same "Spark"-o-train does not help many-models trainings to get run faster once all dataFrame has to get "through" and all resources are kept busy.